# On using "understand more"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Is this sentence correct?

> This is the problem we want to understand more.

Comment: What is the specific difficulty that you have with this sentence.  Why do you think it might be wrong? How would you try to fix it.  Please give details of what you think about this sentence.  Also where has this sentence come from? did you write it yourself? what was the context.

Comment: Yes. I wrote it myself. I describe a scientific problem before. Then I wrote it. I think I never used it that's why I am not sure it is correct.

Comment: Ok, so what is the specific concern? What do you think could be wrong with the grammar or meaning here?

Comment: Potentially, the following would be considered more natural—at least in formal writing: *This is the problem we want to **better understand**.* But there's nothing ungrammatical about what you wrote. And one being better than the other here is simply a question of style.